# How to stop CDialog(mfc) from flickering on Invalidate when updating a RichEdit20A

Tags: c++, mfc, cdialog

I have a timer that I display to the user in a `RichEdit20A` that is inside a `CDialog`.
The problem is every time I update the `RichEdit20A`, the screen flickers.

Since I have several `RichEdit20A` in my Dialog, I have a method below that I use to update them. I have tried `ModifyStyle(0, WS_CLIPCHILDREN, 0);` 
`OnInitDialog` but it erases all my `RichEdit20A` texts. I also tried `RedrawWindow(Null,Null, RDW_Erase)`--Dialog still flickers and `RedrawWindow(Null,Null, RDW_Invalidate)`--All the text gets written on top of the old one making it unreadable.

```
//UpdateData(TRUE);

if(!pRECtrl)
    return;

CHARFORMAT cf = {0};

cf.cbSize = sizeof(cf);
cf.dwMask = (bold ? CFM_BOLD : 0) | (italic ? CFM_ITALIC : 0) | CFM_COLOR;
cf.dwEffects = (bold ? CFE_BOLD : 0) | (italic ? CFE_ITALIC : 0) |~CFE_AUTOCOLOR;
cf.crTextColor = color;

pRECtrl->SetSel(0, -1); // Set the cursor to the end of the text area and deselect everything.
pRECtrl->Clear();
pRECtrl->ReplaceSel(text);

// Apply formating to the just inserted text.
pRECtrl->SetSel(0, pRECtrl->GetTextLength());
pRECtrl->SetSelectionCharFormat(cf);


//UpdateData(FALSE);

Invalidate();
```

I know that Invalidate is what is causing the flickering and that double buffering(I've never done it before) is what is used to fix this kind of issue for CViews...and I don't know what to do to stop the flickering  for a CDialog, which is the window I am using for my program. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Use the [`SetEventMask()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cricheditctrl-class?view=vs-2019#seteventmask) method to disable notifications (especially `EN_SELCHANGE`) from the RichEdit while you are manipulating it, then restore the previous mask when finished. See [Notifications from a Rich Edit Control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/notifications-from-a-rich-edit-control?view=vs-2019).  Also, instead of using `SetSel(0, -1)`+`Clear()`+`ReplaceSel()` as 3 separate operations, consider using the `WM_SETTEXT` or `EM_SETTEXTEX` message as 1 operation instead.

Comment: Use [`m_richedit.SetRedraw(FALSE)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=vs-2019#setredraw) to prevent changes to rich_edit from being shown, then put `m_richedit.SetRedraw(TRUE)` when control is ready. This should stop the rich_edit flicker. I am not sure what you mean by dialog flicker, or screen flicker.

Comment: Not sure how to use SetEventMask() in this context but I tried SetRedraw and it works fine. but the RichEdit only get's drawn once on initDialog but it does not get Redrawn when I call my function again. I put  SetRedraw(FALSE) AND SetRedraw(TRUE) inside my function. By Dialog or Screen flicker I mean that everything on my dialog gets erased and redrawn every time I call my function which causes a noticeable flicker.

Comment: After `m_richedit.SetRedraw(TRUE)` you want to put `m_richedit.Invalidate()` or `m_richedit.SetSel(0,0)` - Your dialog has `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` flag? Don't remove that flag with `ModifyStyle`. You might not need to call `Invalidate` or `RedrawWindow` for the dialog

Comment: yes my dialog has ModifyStyle(0, WS_CLIPCHILDREN, 0); and unfortunately I've tried all your suggestions in all combinations possible and I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Why do you need to call `Invalidate()` (for the whole dialog)? The commands before it should update the rich-edit boxes. You may even call `RedrawWindow()', but for each rich-edit control, not the dialog, if you want an immediate update. But i think this is not needed either, controls have their own invalidate/paint functionality.